# Access first element of pointer to vector of object pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I declare a shared_ptr to a vector of shared_ptr's to objects like so ...

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<my_obj_t>>> vec =
    std::make_shared<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<my_obj_t>>>();
```

My problem is I need to access the first element in the array used internally by the vector. Before changing this to a shared_ptr of objects, it was just an object and I used data().

But now with the vector of shared_ptr's, I'm not sure how to access that first element so that I can add an offset to it and return a pointer of my_obj_t.

I'm trying to use something like

```
(my_vec->data() + offset)
```

... where func requires a pointer to an array of my_obj_t's.

Thoughts?

**Update:**
Before I was using it as ...

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<my_obj_t>> vec =
    std::make_shared<std::vector<my_obj_t>>();
```

And I would access it by

```
(vec->data() + offset)
```

Comment: `(*my_vec)[offset]->get()` seems the most obvious and cleanest.

Comment: You cannot interchange _"pointer to an array of `my_obj_t`"_ and _"pointer to an array of `std::shared_ptr<my_obj_t>`"_.  They are fundamentally different.

Comment: No can do if I'm reading this right. The `vector` now contains an array of  `std::shared_ptr<my_obj_t>`s. To get an array of `my_obj_t`'s you'll have to do a bunch of copying. I'm with @uneven_mark  on this. I think you may be crossing over [into X-Y territory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @ChrisDodd - if you'd like to make an answer, I used yours. Though it was (*my_vec)[offset].get() ... instead of ->get().

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris apparently didn't get around to making an answer, and since it was cleanest, this is what I used.

```
(*my_vec)[offset]->get()
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a reference to the `my_obj_t` pointed to from `offset`

```
*my_vec->at(offset)
```

There *isn't* an array of `my_obj_t` *anywhere*

Answer (score 0):

```
std::make_shared<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<my_obj_t>>>()
```

This constructs an empty vector of `shared_ptr`s.

> My problem is I need to access the first element in the array used
>   internally by the vector.

Since the vector is empty, the internal array you are imagining probably doesn't exist yet.  So there is no way to access the first element of it.  You have to add the elements before trying to use them.